# Is there a word for the act of simultaneously pulling and twisting an object?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have the impression I once saw a word's definition the meaning of which was exactly that, the act of **forcefully** pulling and twisting an object (e.g from someone's hands).

Another example would be if I was to break a branch off a tree, and just pulling or twisting it wouldn't be enough, so I should be doing both simultaneously.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[wrench](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wrench)

Definitions including pulling and twisting follow (M-W).

intransitive verb (2):

> to pull or strain at something with violent twisting

transitive verb (4a):

> to pull or tighten by violent twisting or with violence

noun (1a):

> a violent twisting or a pull with or as if with twisting

Example sentence found online ([Pal Item dated June 9, 2019](https://www.pal-item.com/story/news/local/2019/06/09/out-our-past-ferocious-winds-created-nightmarish-problems-1963/1327895001/)):

> Violent winds downed trees and wrenched off tree limbs in a frenzy of
>   nature at its most ruthless.

Synonym: [wrest](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wrest) (M-W, English Language Learners Definition, 1 of 2):

> to pull (something) away from someone by using violent twisting
>   movements

Comment: There's also *wrest*.  You can *wrest* something from someone.  It's similar to *wrench*.

Comment: KannE - oh, I see it now.  Don't know how I missed it....